# libraries for lz4 compression codec not found - kafka python

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-python

Error using kafka python (kafka-python 1.4.7)

Kafka Consumer throwing error

> kafka.errors.UnsupportedCodecError: UnsupportedCodecError: libraries for lz4 compression codec not found

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution while I was reading the docs

https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/install.html

Just installed lz4 using pip and restarted it.

> pip install lz4